# Firefox unexpected line break using floats & overflow hidden

Tags: css, firefox, css-float, overflow

I have a container div that holds two items: a `.button` and a `.box` with text inside. `.button` comes first and is floated right. `.box` has no float [this is a constraint - I can't float it left due to similar other structures that depend on there being no float]. `.box` has `overflow: hidden;` to establish a new block formatting context. This allows `.box` to span "100% up to" the prior floated element, `.button`.

`.outer-container` houses all of these and is floated right.

http://jsfiddle.net/6qAwA/5/

In Chrome (26.0.1410.12 beta-m PC, 25.0.1364.99 Mac), Safari (6.0.2 Mac), and IE8-9, this will act in a desired way. `.box`'s text stays on one line, and due to `.outer-container`'s right float, will be exactly the size it needs to be. In Firefox, however, the text is broken into another line.

[image]

I also find a similar issue when `.button` is instead floated left - I get desired behavior in everything except for Firefox.

I've seen this Firefox 16.0.1 and 19.0 for PC, and 18.0.1 and 19.0 for Mac. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.box`:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6qAwA/14)

Comment: This works exactly for the purpose of the original Fiddle, but unfortunately it's not exactly what I'm looking for, since I need "outer-containers" to be a little more flexible. If the `.outer-container` wasn't floated, the `.box` should still span "100% up to" the prior floated element because of `overflow: hidden;`, while the whole thing spans 100%. [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/MLtLMjp.png), [new Fiddle without inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/6qAwA/11/)

Comment: Got it.. I suppose in the case of having one `.box`, I can meet in the middle and use a more specific selector to add `display: inline-block;`. [new Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qAwA/16/). It's still strange though, and I don't know that this fix makes the issue seem like any less of a bug in FF.

Answer (score 42):

I came across this issue today where the **floating node** would break line only in Firefox even after setting its `display` to `inline-block` and the reason for that was that the **container node** had a style setting of `white-space` set to `nowrap`.
So resetting the value of `white-space` to `normal` on the **container node** resolved this issue for me.

Comment: This worked for me - the container element was a button and setting it to `white-space: normal` fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Works. But Why? especially since it seems crazy that nowrap makes it wrap to next line...

Comment: If you need `nowrap` for your container, then I'd suggest this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26306907/2550529

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you are going for a solution like
http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/x5rPd/
you don't need a second `div` for your desired behavior.

Comment: This also makes sense for the original issue, but for the purposes of the project I'm working on, that block-level element is required.

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: normal` didn't do the trick for me. What worked was `white-space: nowrap;` on the direct text container.