# Firefox float bug? How do I get my float:right on the same line?

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

I have the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q05n5v4c/2/

In Chrome, it renders just fine.  The chevron is on the right side.

However, in Firefox, it drops the Chevron down 1 line.

I've searched google and found several posts about this bug, but none of the suggestions have helped.

Any CSS experts out there that can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Html:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" 
            class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
            style="width: 400px;text-align: left;">

        Checked option 

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" 
              style='float: right;'></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Change the order of the float, put it before the text like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"style="width: 400px;text-align: left;">        
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style='float: right;'></span>
    Checked option
  </button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q05n5v4c/3/

Answer (score 64):

It seems like the property `white-space` is the cause of the issue. With the class `btn` this property is:

> white-space:nowrap

If you change that property works fine:

```
.btn {
    white-space:normal
}
```

Check the [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q05n5v4c/5/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful even though I wasn't using the same classes. The ones I was using had this white-space:nowrap set though!

Comment: Gald to help U mate @ShaaradDalvi

Comment: Cleanest solution

Comment: But what if we want the `nowrap`?

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer, the other answer might cause accessibility issues. I like this answer better :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't wish to reverse the order of your elements, you could `float: left;` the first element.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the float on the span, add `position: absolute` to it and position it using top/right/bottom/left.
Note: .btn-group already have `position: relative` from bootstrap.

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="width: 400px;text-align: left;">        
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    Checked option
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.btn-group span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 12px;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64vm5zru/4/).

Answer (score -2):

Here is one more solution:

give style your span tag like this.

```
position:absolute;
right: 5px;
top : 9px
```

Comment: i dont know why this is not an answer, i always used left and that coused many problem but using right with abcelute position is really helpful thanx man.