# Pure css pure-menu-heading not aligning with items in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

Pure css pure-menu-heading not aligning with items in Firefox? To see run this on Firefox,http://purecss.io/layouts/marketing/. 'YOUR SITE' pure-menu-heading is above the pure-menu-item items but aligns well in Chromium and Opera. Also class 'header' is not in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/combo/1.18.13?/css/layouts/marketing.css">?
```

Comment: add your minimized code

Comment: just view source of http://purecss.io/layouts/marketing/ for html and in it <link rel="stylesheet" href="/combo/1.18.13?/css/layouts/marketing.css"> for css.

Comment: We need a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Questions asking to debug a problem should provide a reproducible example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

you need to `float:left` the "your site" (`.home-menu .pure-menu-heading`) that fixes it

the reason this happens in firefox (according to this answer [Firefox unexpected line break using floats & overflow hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102575/firefox-unexpected-line-break-using-floats-overflow-hidden#18101700) - and also checked) is that firefox set default `white-space` to `nowrap`.

so setting the wrapper div `.pure-menu.pure-menu-fixed` to `white-space:normal` also fixes this issue and might actually be a better solution for you

Comment: why only for firefox?

Comment: `.pure-menu.pure-menu-fixed{white-space:normal}` tested and works

Answer (score 1):

Just add `float: left` to `.pure-menu-heading`. Like:

```
.pure-menu-heading {
  float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why only for firefox?

Comment: @user7339197 According to me this is because of different specs on both the browsers. Chrome runs on webkit engine & Firefox runs on gecko engine. Firefox adds `white-space`

Answer (score 0):

change your HTML like below

```
<div class="home-menu pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-fixed">
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Tour</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
<a class="pure-menu-heading" href="">Your Site</a>     
</div>
```

put anchor tag after ul

Comment: anchor tag is taking its own space in firefox and ul start after the space occupied by anchor